# Gradle - Exclude spring.xml from a dependency

Tags: java, spring, gradle

Is there a way to exclude spring.xml from a gradle dependency? I have enabled autoscanning for all spring.xmls but do not want spring.xml from a specific jar to considered.

```
compile('com.savnet.ofm:ofm-client:16.08') {
    exclude group: "net.sf.saxon", module: "saxon-xpath"
    exclude group: 'hibernate'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean excluding a file from a JAR you depend on?

If so, then as far as I know there is no per-se supported way.
But you can make it manually.
Something like the following *which is totally made up right now and not tested*, so take this as a starting point that might work or might need some polishing to work.

```
configurations { foo }
dependencies { foo 'com.savnet.ofm:ofm-client:16.08'}
sourceSets { main.compileClasspath += configurations.foo }

task fooJar(type: Jar) {
    archiveName = 'foo.jar'
    from zipTree(configurations.foo.singleFile)
    exclude 'spring.xml'
}
```

And then use `fooJar` output as runtime library.

Comment: Thanks @Vampire. How can I define it as runtime dependency?

Comment: I think you got me wrong because I choosed the wrong final word. Not as dependency in the dependency block of Gradle, but as runtime library for however you ship your project. If it is a standalone app, add it to the lib folder, if it is an EAR, at it to its lib folder, if its a WAR, add it there where it belongs, .... I cannot answer this without knowing your project.